# Como usar el ISNULL en Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Cual es la forma correcta de utilizar el **ISNULL** en Entity Framework.

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
declare @x nvarchar(3);
set @x= null;
select * from [clientes] where ClienteId= isnull(@x,clienteid)
```

El resultado si la variable x es null debería regresar todo los registros de la tabla.
Si la variable x tiene valor debería filtrar solo por ese valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer uso de **Linq** para realizar las consultas orientadas a objetos:

```
MiContexto db = new MiContexto();
List<clientes> lista = new List<clientes>();

if(x == null)
{
   lista = db.clientes.ToList();
}
else
{
   lista = db.clientes.Where(c => c.ClienteId == x).ToList();
}
```

Lo primero que hacemos es declarar el contexto(Yo aquí le doy como nombre al contexto **MiContexto**, en tu caso quizá le hayas dado otro nombre o quizá lo dejaste con el nombre por defecto que es **Model1Container**) lo cual no es mas que el nombre que se le da a la base de datos cuando **EntityFramework** la mapea, también declaramos una lista de **tipo clientes** la cual almacenará el resultado de las consultas que hagamos. Posteriormente preguntaríamos si la **variable x** es **null**, de serlo guardaríamos en la **variable lista** todos los clientes, de no ser **null** la **variable x** entonces haríamos el filtro correspondiente.

Para hacer uso de **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```